# Accessing an F# list from inside C# code

Tags: c#, list, types, f#

I have written an F# module that has a list inside:

```ml
module MyModule
type X = 
    {
        valuex : float32
    }
let l = [ for i in 1 .. 10 -> {valuex =  3.3f}]
```

Now from a C# class I'm trying to access the previously defined list, but I don't know how converting it:

```cs
... list = MyModule.l ; //here's my problem
```

I'd need something like:

```cs
IList<X> list = MyModule.l;
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As simple as:

```
IList<MyModule.X> list = MyModule.l.ToList();
```

The reason you need the conversion method rather than a cast / implicit conversion is because an `FSharpList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but not `IList<T>` since it represents an immutable linked-list.

Note that you'll have to include `FSharp.Core` as a reference in your C# project.

Answer (score 6):

The [`FSharpList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx) (which is the .Net name of the F# `list<T>` type) doesn't implement `IList<T>`, because it doesn't make sense.

`IList<T>` is for accessing and modifying collections that can be accessed by index, which `list<T>` is not. To use it from C#, you can either use the type explicitly:

```
FSharpList<MyModule.X> l = MyModule.l;
var l = MyModule.l; // the same as above
```

Or you can use the fact that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<MyModule.X> l = MyModule.l;
```

Or, if you do need `IList<T>`, you can use LINQ's `ToList()`, as Ani suggested:

```
IList<MyModule.X> l = MyModule.l.ToList();
```

But you have to remember that F# list is immutable and so there is no way to modify it.

Comment: yes thanks for the suggestion..I know about immutable, but I don't need to modify the list. Just retrieve some values in it to be rendered using XNA and C#