# Accessing an F# List<List<>> from inside C# code

Tags: c#, list, f#

this is an extension of [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245925/587884).
I thought that accessing a `List<List<>>` would be quite similar to a simple list, but I have some problem.

Here's the F# code:

```ml
type X = 
    {
        valuex : int
    }
let l = 
    [
    for i in 1 .. 10 -> 
        [
        for j in 1 .. 10 ->
            {valuex =  i * j}
        ]

    ]
```

Accordingly to my previous post I tried to do the following inside C# code:

```cs
IList<IList<MyModule.X>> list = MyModule.l.ToList();
```

but this don't compile.
Can someone which is my error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the type of the property is `FSharpList<FSharpList<MyModule.X>>` So you'll have to map each inner FSharpList to an `IList<T>` and then materialize the resulting sequence to a list (of lists).

This would look like:

```
IList<IList<MyModule.X>> list = MyModule.l
                                        .Select(inner => (IList<MyModule.X>) inner.ToList())
                                        .ToList();
```

Do you really need all these *precise* conversions? Isn't the fact that the collection is already an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` good enough? In fact, `FSharpList<T>` itself is quite a usable type from C#, so I would stay away from these conversions unless absolutely necessary.

**EDIT**:

If you just need to iterate the elements, all you need is a loop:

```
foreach(var innerList in MyModule.l)
{
    foreach(var item in innerList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.valuex);
    }     
}
```

Comment: well, actually I don't know. I'm a C# and F# newbie. The point is that I have a List<List> in f# and I have to iterate through it in C#. If you know a better solution, please! put me in the right direction.

Comment: Declaring the variable of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyModule.X>>` then iterate/enumerate to your hearts content. :) As long as something implements `IEnumerable<T>` it can be iterated on without having to know the exact/concrete type.