# Accessing an F# Map from inside C# code

Tags: c#, f#, dictionary

Is there any simple way to access an F# Map from inside C# code?

I mean, both C# and F# lists are enumerable so I can iterate an F# list from inside C# code just through that interface, like explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245925/587884).

Suppose I've declared such a Map inside a F# module called module.fs:

```
let MyMap : Map<string,T>>
```

I would like to access the map from inside C# this way:

```
Map m = module.MyMap;
```

Is possible to do something like this without performing conversions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` is called `FSharpMap` when accessed outside F#. You could use `var` to avoid the awkward type name (in your example). However, most F#-specific types implement interfaces that play well across language boundaries. For instance, `Map` implements `IDictionary<_,_>`. In APIs that will be used outside F#, the recommended solution is to expose those interfaces instead.

Check out the [Component Design Guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) for more recommendations.

Having said that, you can use `FSharpMap` from C# without any trouble. It just looks weird and doesn't lend itself to idiomatic C# code.